# PHP How to show milliseconds using my existing function

Tags: php, function, time, duration

I used  [Jean Caffou's](http://dev.kafol.net/2008/09/php-calculating-time-span-duration.html) function and tweaked it a tiny bit.
Now I want to not only let it calculate seconds, but also milliseconds.

Any idea how to do that?

```
################################################
/**
 * [Duration kalkuliert Zeitunterschied zwischen zwei Daten]
 * @param [unix timestamp] $start
 * @param [unix timestamp] $end (optional)
 * @return [string] $duration z.B. "4 Tage 3 Stunden 34 Sekunden"
 * Danke an: Jean Caffou http://dev.kafol.net/2008/09/php-calculating-time-span-duration.html
 */
function Duration($start,$end=null) {
    $end = is_null($end) ? time() : $end;

    $seconds = $end - $start;

    $days = floor($seconds/60/60/24);
    $hours = $seconds/60/60%24;
    $mins = $seconds/60%60;
    $secs = $seconds%60;

    $duration='';
    if($days>1) $duration .= "$days Tage ";
    if($days==1) $duration .= "$days Tag ";
    if($hours==1) $duration .= "$hours Stunde ";
    if($hours>1) $duration .= "$hours Stunden ";
    if($mins==1) $duration .= "$mins Minute ";
    if($mins>1) $duration .= "$mins Minuten ";
    if($secs==1) $duration .= "$secs Sekunde ";
    if($secs>1) $duration .= "$secs Sekunden ";

    $duration = trim($duration);
    if($duration==null) $duration = '0 Sekunden';

    return $duration;
}# Duration Ende
################################################
```

I want it to output something like:
**1 Minute, 30 seconds, 345 milliseconds.**

Answer (score 0):

```
 * @param [unix timestamp] $start
 * @param [unix timestamp] $end (optional)
```

Is your problem, They are both ints. meaning no miliseconds. Look at using the DateTime class which does support it

http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.datetime.php